# "Negotiationneeded" event and RTCPeerConnection.addTrack() combination in webrtc

Tags: webrtc

My program (in javascript) calls `RTCPeerConnection.addTrack` several times (when there are several tracks should be added) while setting up a webrtc connection.

Will the event `negotiationneeded` be fired every time I call addTrack() ?

If yes, what I should do to force this event to be fired after I add all my track – 1 time.